# How to fix "incompatible type" error in C?

Tags: c, types

I'm creating the * create Schedule () function to generate a schedule of the ScheduleData data type, but I get the error: incompatible type when assigning to type 'ScheduleData'. could some one help me how to solve this ?

In the Schedule * function createSchedule (), in the line schedule-> node [i] [j] = schData;
error occurs

```
struct ScheduleData {
    char *initials;
    char *classroom;
    char *teacher;
};
struct Schedule {

    ScheduleData node[8][6];
};

Schedule *createSchedule() {

    Schedule *schedule = malloc(sizeof(Schedule));

    ScheduleData *schData;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            schData = malloc(sizeof(ScheduleData));
            schData -> initials = NULL;
            schData -> classroom = NULL;
            schData -> teacher = NULL;
            schedule->node[i][j] = schData;

        }
    return schedule;
}
```

Comment: Use a compatible type?  Your `struct Schedule` holds an array of actual `struct ScheduleData` structures; you try to assign pointers to these structures, and the compiler objects.  You don't need the `malloc()` operations in the nested loops (or the assignment to `schedule->node[i][j]`) — or you need `ScheduleData *node[8][6];`.  I recommend not using `malloc()` in the loops.

Comment: @ocich93, are you using C and C++? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ManthanTilva Obviously C++. C would explicitly require a `typedef ... ScheduleData` or a `struct` before `ScheduleData`.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Then Tag for C++ must need to add.

Answer (score 3):

Your `struct Schedule` holds an array of actual `struct ScheduleData` structures; you try to assign pointers to these structures, and the compiler objects.  You don't need the `malloc()` operations in the nested loops (or the assignment to `schedule->node[i][j]`) — or you need `ScheduleData *node[8][6];`.  I recommend not using `malloc()` in the loops.

Also, as [Martin Rosenau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705055/martin-rosenau) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033735/how-to-fix-incompatible-type-error-in-c/57033824#comment100596235_57033735), a C compiler does not generate a name `Schedule` (in the 'ordinary identifiers' namespace) given a declaration `struct Schedule { … };` — although a C++ compiler does.  You need to add:

```
typedef struct Schedule Schedule;
typedef struct ScheduleData ScheduleData;
```

before you use the names `Schedule` or `ScheduleData` without the prior `struct`.  If you are writing C++ and not C, then you need to fix the tag o the question and you need to stop using `malloc()` et al.  If you must use `malloc()` et al in C++, you will need explicit casts to convert the `void *` to the correct type — the cast is unnecessary in C.

#### Fewer calls to `malloc()`

```
Schedule *createSchedule(void)
{
    Schedule *schedule = calloc(sizeof(Schedule), 1);
    return schedule;
}
```

The use of `calloc()` zeroes all the bytes in the structure, which will normally set all the pointers to NULL, etc.  (The onus is on the calling code to check that a null pointer is not returned.)  Alternatively:

```
Schedule *createSchedule()
{
    Schedule *schedule = malloc(sizeof(Schedule));
    if (schedule != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                schedule->data[i][j].initials = NULL;
                schedule->data[i][j].classroom = NULL;
                schedule->data[i][j].teacher = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return schedule;
}
```

You could also use `memset()` to zero the data provided by `malloc()`, but using `calloc()` will do that at least as efficiently.

#### Continuing to use `malloc()` copiously

Change the type of `struct Schedule` to:

```
struct Schedule
{
    ScheduleData *node[8][6];
};
```

Note that this uses a lot more memory (there is overhead for each allocation), and the structure is a lot harder to free (you need 49 calls to `free()` instead of just 1).

#### Style guide

1. Always check that memory allocation functions report success before using the result.
2. Do not put a space around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators.  They bind incredibly tightly; the space is unwarranted, aconventional, and makes your code harder to read.
3. Do use explicit `Schedule *createSchedule(void)` in both function declarations and definitions to indicate no arguments.  C is not C++; the rules are different between the two.  And being explicit about `void` means the compiler will warn you about `createSchedule(32, "pink elephants")` whereas it is not obliged to warn you about the abuse of the function if you do not specify the `void` explicitly — you didn't create a prototype, just a function declaration, if you omit the `void`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Schedule *createSchedule(void)
{
   // make sure you cast the return arg of malloc!
   Schedule *schedule = (Schedule*)malloc(sizeof(Schedule));

   // no need to allocate each 6x8node, already done
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
       schedule->node[j][i]->initials = NULL;
       schedule->node[j][i]->classroom = NULL;
       schedule->node[j][i]->teacher = NULL;
    }
  }
  return schedule;
}
```

Alternatively, since every byte in a Schedule gets set to 0, you could just use `memset()` after creation here:

```
Schedule *createSchedule(void)
{
   // make sure you cast the return arg of malloc!
   Schedule *schedule = (Schedule*)malloc(sizeof(Schedule));
   memset(schedule, 0, sizeof(Schedule));
   return schedule;
}
```

Comment: Quote: "make sure you cast the return arg of malloc!"  Hmm, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: `calloc` is better than `malloc` followed by `memset`  (clearer and might be faster)

Comment: Worth noting that setting the bits of a pointer’s object representation to zero is technically non-portable behavior, and potentially could be undefined behavior on some target. Most C compilers do represent NULL as all-bits-set-to-zero, but there have historically been some mainframe compilers where that wasn’t the case, and the language Standard doesn’t require it. In practice, the optimizer should be able to compile the NULL assignments as efficiently as a `memset()`.

Comment: However, the Standard does say that initializing a structure with a list of members in braces, such as `{.foo = bar}` or `{}`, does portably set all pointer members not listed to `NULL`. More generally, it implicitly sets all members left over as if they were`static`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to fix “incompatible type” error in C?

You need to ask two questions:

> What type is `schedule->node[i][j]` ?

Answer: It is `ScheduleData`

> What type is `schData` ?

Answer: It is `ScheduleData *`  (i.e. pointer to `ScheduleData`)

As the two variables have different types, you'll get a compilation error.

To fix it, you need to change the type of one of the variables to match the other.

From your code it seems that you would want to change `schedule->node[i][j]` to be a `ScheduleData *`. So all you need to do is:

```
struct Schedule {    
    ScheduleData *node[8][6];
    //  notice   ^  
};
```

BTW: You have tagged the question C but it seems that you use a C++ compiler. If you really want C++ then fix the tag. If you really want C, use a C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not an actual answer but an extension to [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033735/how-to-fix-incompatible-type-error-in-c#57033824):

I have read questions like yours very often. In most cases there is a misconception caused by comparing C and C++ with Java or C#:

In Java variables of primitive data types (like `int`) hold values while values of `class` data types hold references to objects.

"Reference" means that in the following program:

```
ScheduleData a = b;
a.initials = "ab";
b.initials = "xy";
```

... the **same** variable is accessed by the statements `a.initials` and `b.initials`.

However, **C and C++ work differently**:

You decide if a variable is a "pointer" (which more or less is a "reference") or if it is a value by using or not using an asterisk (`*`) between the data type and the variable name. Example:

```
ScheduleData a, *b;
int c, *d, *e;
d = e;
```

In this example the variables `a` and `c` hold values, the variables `b`, `d` and `e` hold references.

And just like in the Java example modifying the value `d` points to will have the same effect as modifying the value `e` points to because `d` and `e` are references to the same integer.

The first solution in Jonathan Leffler's answer proposes using values of the data type `ScheduleData` instead of using references.

The second solution shows you how references are used. Avoiding references typically makes programming easier but references may be required if you want to do the equivalent of the following Java program:

```
ScheduleData x = node[4][2];
ScheduleData y = node[4][2];
node[4][2] = new ScheduleData();
/* x and y will be a reference to the same data structure but node[4][2]
 * is a reference to a different data structure */
```

**By the way**

The program you have written is a C++ program, not a C program.

Unlke C++, C will not automatically recognize structure names as data types. Instead, you either have to define the data type using `typedef`:

```
typedef struct _s_ScheduleData {
    ...
} ScheduleData;
```

... or you have to use the `struct` keyword as part of the data type:

```
struct ScheduleData node[8][6];
```

Comment: Strictly, it wasn't a C++ program either; the result of `malloc()` must be cast (from `void *` to the required type) in C++, though the cast is not necessary in C.  It was an uncomfortable hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the loops with a simple assignment:

```
Schedule *createSchedule(void) {
//                       ^^^^ use this to indicate no parameters

    Schedule *schedule = malloc(sizeof(Schedule));
    *schedule = (Schedule){0};
    return schedule;
}
```

The `(Schedule){0}` creates a temporary object and the initializer means any pointers will be set to null pointers.

If your compiler is very old then the assignment line can be replaced with `Schedule blank = {0}; *schedule = blank;`.